# I have set PyCharm interpreter right but when run the code, it shows in the run window PyCharm uses another python.exe I used before

Tags: python, pycharm

From the image, you can see that I have set the project interpreter right. But when I run the code, it uses another *python.exe* which I set before. I have tried to set an interpreter in both settings and default settings and install the newest version of PyCharm, but they do not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a different interpreter set for this specific run configuration. Check it in *Run | Edit Configurations*:

[image]